# How to retrieve the SNMP configuration on existing Jboss RHQ server?

Tags: java, networking, snmp, serve, rhq

I currently facing a wall at work. We have an old JON Rhq server v3.2 and a recently installed JON Rhq server v3.3. The old one could not be updated nor patched, so it was decided to install the new one.

They are installed on different VM.

I was not part of the installations but it falls to my team to make it work.

The issue today is that the old RHQ server is able to send SnmpTrap Messages which contains info in 12 fields , whereas the new Rhq Server only sends 7 fields, and we can't find the configuration behind that behaviour.

I checked the [rhq-jboss-server]/etc/RHQ-mib.txt files on both but nothing different.

I went through the snmpd.conf files on both and still nothing different.

I tried to go through the configuration files you can retrieve via the following command:

```py
snmpd -Dread_config -H 2>&1 | grep "config path" | sort -u
```

but still the same.

I think there is some hidden configuration or MIB files I'm missing.

Hope you can give me directions where to look for it.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

we can close this subject. Actually, the initial team developped their own plugin to generate SNMP trap messages.
It was the detail we missed and by copying the jar from this plugin into the new instance of rhq server, everything worked .

Cheers